# www-data user added to group not able to write/delete in folder with group permissions

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I have a web app that will execute a perl script via PHP to allow users to clear out old logs. The same script is to be used by cron.
Currently I get a permissions error when this is run. www-data is executing the script.
If I chmod 777 the directories it works but don't want to do that.
Created a new group and added the directory owner and www-data to it. Chowned the directory for the owner and new group and ran chmod -R g+s. This still doesn't work.
Have found a few posts that said to do exactly what I did for the solution.

What am I missing here?

*logs1 is directory containing files/directories to be cleared, logs1 itself will not be deleted.*

Does not work:
`drwxrwxr-x    9 foo  foo         32768 Jun 9  2017 logs1`

Works (don't want to do):
`drwxrwxrwx    9 foo  foo         32768 Jun 9  2017 logs1`

Works (don't want to do):
`drwxrwxr-x    9 www-data  www-data    32768 Jun 9  2017 logs1`

`groupadd newgroup`
`usermod -a -G newgroup foo`
`usermod -a -G newgroup www-data`
`chown foo:newgroup logs1`
`chmod -R g+s logs1`

Still doesn't work:
`drwxrwxr-x    9 foo  newgroup    32768 Jun 9  2017 logs1`

Thanks

Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2, php 7, perl v5.18.2

Comment: There is no Perl content in this question.

Comment: Perl script is being used for deletions, Was trying to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart your webserver? Changes to secondary groups of a user do not affect running processes.

Comment: I hadn't. Three days ago i ran: 
`newgrp newgroup` 
and permissions began to work correctly. This doesn't make sense to me because that should only affect the current shell and the problem I was having had to do with apache.
I have since restarted the webserver to be on the safe side.